# typeorm yields syntax error at or near "ORDER"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typeorm

I'm getting this error when the following DB request gets executed:

```js
const entriesDB = await this.entryRepository.createQueryBuilder('entry')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('entry.categories', 'categories')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('categories.parentCategory', 'parent')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('entry.images', 'images')
    .where(whereClause, filters)
    .orderBy('categories.position', 'ASC')
    .getMany();
```

What is wrong with the request?

EDIT:

Here is the full debug/traceback message:

```
query: SELECT DISTINCT "distinctAlias"."UserEntity_id" as "ids_UserEntity_id" FROM (SELECT "UserEntity"."id" AS "UserEntity_id", "UserEntity"."first_name" AS "UserEntity_first_name", "UserEntity"."last_name" AS "UserEntity_last_name", "UserEntity"."phone" AS "UserEntity_phone", "UserEntity"."password" AS "UserEntity_password", "UserEntity"."password_hint" AS "UserEntity_password_hint", "UserEntity"."recovery_email" AS "UserEntity_recovery_email", "UserEntity"."created" AS "UserEntity_created", "UserEntity"."username" AS "UserEntity_username", "UserEntity"."profile_pic" AS "UserEntity_profile_pic", "UserEntity"."is2FA" AS "UserEntity_is2FA", "UserEntity"."refresh_token" AS "UserEntity_refresh_token", "UserEntity"."subscriptionId" AS "UserEntity_subscriptionId", "UserEntity__subscription"."id" AS "UserEntity__subscription_id", "UserEntity__subscription"."type" AS "UserEntity__subscription_type", "UserEntity__subscription"."isActive" AS "UserEntity__subscription_isActive", "UserEntity__subscription"."activatedOn" AS "UserEntity__subscription_activatedOn" FROM "user" "UserEntity" LEFT JOIN "subscription" "UserEntity__subscription" ON "UserEntity__subscription"."id"="UserEntity"."subscriptionId" WHERE "UserEntity"."phone" = $1) "distinctAlias" ORDER BY "UserEntity_id" ASC LIMIT 1 -- PARAMETERS: ["79509231601"]
query: SELECT "UserEntity"."id" AS "UserEntity_id", "UserEntity"."first_name" AS "UserEntity_first_name", "UserEntity"."last_name" AS "UserEntity_last_name", "UserEntity"."phone" AS "UserEntity_phone", "UserEntity"."password" AS "UserEntity_password", "UserEntity"."password_hint" AS "UserEntity_password_hint", "UserEntity"."recovery_email" AS "UserEntity_recovery_email", "UserEntity"."created" AS "UserEntity_created", "UserEntity"."username" AS "UserEntity_username", "UserEntity"."profile_pic" AS "UserEntity_profile_pic", "UserEntity"."is2FA" AS "UserEntity_is2FA", "UserEntity"."refresh_token" AS "UserEntity_refresh_token", "UserEntity"."subscriptionId" AS "UserEntity_subscriptionId", "UserEntity__subscription"."id" AS "UserEntity__subscription_id", "UserEntity__subscription"."type" AS "UserEntity__subscription_type", "UserEntity__subscription"."isActive" AS "UserEntity__subscription_isActive", "UserEntity__subscription"."activatedOn" AS "UserEntity__subscription_activatedOn" FROM "user" "UserEntity" LEFT JOIN "subscription" "UserEntity__subscription" ON "UserEntity__subscription"."id"="UserEntity"."subscriptionId" WHERE ("UserEntity"."phone" = $1) AND "UserEntity"."id" IN (1) -- PARAMETERS: ["79509231601"]
query: SELECT "entry"."id" AS "entry_id", "entry"."body" AS "entry_body", "entry"."title" AS "entry_title", "entry"."createdOn" AS "entry_createdOn", "entry"."startDate" AS "entry_startDate", "entry"."start_date_time_zone" AS "entry_start_date_time_zone", "entry"."finishDate" AS "entry_finishDate", "entry"."finish_date_time_zone" AS "entry_finish_date_time_zone", "entry"."state" AS "entry_state", "entry"."is_pinned" AS "entry_is_pinned", "entry"."is_assigned_to_you" AS "entry_is_assigned_to_you", "entry"."clone_of" AS "entry_clone_of", "entry"."remind_at" AS "entry_remind_at", "entry"."all_day" AS "entry_all_day", "entry"."location_name" AS "entry_location_name", "entry"."latitude" AS "entry_latitude", "entry"."longitude" AS "entry_longitude", "categories"."id" AS "categories_id", "categories"."template_id" AS "categories_template_id", "categories"."name" AS "categories_name", "categories"."entry_count" AS "categories_entry_count", "categories"."is_base_template" AS "categories_is_base_template", "categories"."can_rename" AS "categories_can_rename", "categories"."can_delete" AS "categories_can_delete", "categories"."userId" AS "categories_userId", "categories"."position" AS "categories_position", "categories"."icon_path" AS "categories_icon_path", "categories"."init_name" AS "categories_init_name", "categories"."isForTasks" AS "categories_isForTasks", "categories"."parentCategoryId" AS "categories_parentCategoryId", "parent"."id" AS "parent_id", "parent"."template_id" AS "parent_template_id", "parent"."name" AS "parent_name", "parent"."entry_count" AS "parent_entry_count", "parent"."is_base_template" AS "parent_is_base_template", "parent"."can_rename" AS "parent_can_rename", "parent"."can_delete" AS "parent_can_delete", "parent"."userId" AS "parent_userId", "parent"."position" AS "parent_position", "parent"."icon_path" AS "parent_icon_path", "parent"."init_name" AS "parent_init_name", "parent"."isForTasks" AS "parent_isForTasks", "parent"."parentCategoryId" AS "parent_parentCategoryId", "images"."id" AS "images_id", "images"."createdOn" AS "images_createdOn", "images"."updatedOn" AS "images_updatedOn", "images"."size" AS "images_size", "images"."is_private" AS "images_is_private", "images"."name" AS "images_name", "images"."path" AS "images_path" FROM "entry" "entry" LEFT JOIN "category_entries_entry" "categories_entry" ON "categories_entry"."entryId"="entry"."id" LEFT JOIN "category" "categories" ON "categories"."id"="categories_entry"."categoryId"  LEFT JOIN "category" "parent" ON "parent"."id"="categories"."parentCategoryId"  LEFT JOIN "entry_images_image" "entry_images" ON "entry_images"."entryId"="entry"."id" LEFT JOIN "image" "images" ON "images"."id"="entry_images"."imageId" WHERE ("categories"."userId" = $1 OR "parent"."userId" = $2)
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            ; ORDER BY "categories"."position" ASC -- PARAMETERS: [1,1]
query failed: SELECT "entry"."id" AS "entry_id", "entry"."body" AS "entry_body", "entry"."title" AS "entry_title", "entry"."createdOn" AS "entry_createdOn", "entry"."startDate" AS "entry_startDate", "entry"."start_date_time_zone" AS "entry_start_date_time_zone", "entry"."finishDate" AS "entry_finishDate", "entry"."finish_date_time_zone" AS "entry_finish_date_time_zone", "entry"."state" AS "entry_state", "entry"."is_pinned" AS "entry_is_pinned", "entry"."is_assigned_to_you" AS "entry_is_assigned_to_you", "entry"."clone_of" AS "entry_clone_of", "entry"."remind_at" AS "entry_remind_at", "entry"."all_day" AS "entry_all_day", "entry"."location_name" AS "entry_location_name", "entry"."latitude" AS "entry_latitude", "entry"."longitude" AS "entry_longitude", "categories"."id" AS "categories_id", "categories"."template_id" AS "categories_template_id", "categories"."name" AS "categories_name", "categories"."entry_count" AS "categories_entry_count", "categories"."is_base_template" AS "categories_is_base_template", "categories"."can_rename" AS "categories_can_rename", "categories"."can_delete" AS "categories_can_delete", "categories"."userId" AS "categories_userId", "categories"."position" AS "categories_position", "categories"."icon_path" AS "categories_icon_path", "categories"."init_name" AS "categories_init_name", "categories"."isForTasks" AS "categories_isForTasks", "categories"."parentCategoryId" AS "categories_parentCategoryId", "parent"."id" AS "parent_id", "parent"."template_id" AS "parent_template_id", "parent"."name" AS "parent_name", "parent"."entry_count" AS "parent_entry_count", "parent"."is_base_template" AS "parent_is_base_template", "parent"."can_rename" AS "parent_can_rename", "parent"."can_delete" AS "parent_can_delete", "parent"."userId" AS "parent_userId", "parent"."position" AS "parent_position", "parent"."icon_path" AS "parent_icon_path", "parent"."init_name" AS "parent_init_name", "parent"."isForTasks" AS "parent_isForTasks", "parent"."parentCategoryId" AS "parent_parentCategoryId", "images"."id" AS "images_id", "images"."createdOn" AS "images_createdOn", "images"."updatedOn" AS "images_updatedOn", "images"."size" AS "images_size", "images"."is_private" AS "images_is_private", "images"."name" AS "images_name", "images"."path" AS "images_path" FROM "entry" "entry" LEFT JOIN "category_entries_entry" "categories_entry" ON "categories_entry"."entryId"="entry"."id" LEFT JOIN "category" "categories" ON "categories"."id"="categories_entry"."categoryId"  LEFT JOIN "category" "parent" ON "parent"."id"="categories"."parentCategoryId"  LEFT JOIN "entry_images_image" "entry_images" ON "entry_images"."entryId"="entry"."id" LEFT JOIN "image" "images" ON "images"."id"="entry_images"."imageId" WHERE ("categories"."userId" = $1 OR "parent"."userId" = $2)
                            
                            
                            
                            
                            ; ORDER BY "categories"."position" ASC -- PARAMETERS: [1,1]
error: error: syntax error at or near "ORDER"
    at Connection.parseE (/home/albert/Documents/projects/rjx/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:581:48)
    at Connection.parseMessage (/home/albert/Documents/projects/rjx/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:380:19)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/albert/Documents/projects/rjx/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:116:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:273:9)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:214:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23) {
  name: 'error',
  length: 96,
  severity: 'ERROR',
  code: '42601',
  detail: undefined,
  hint: undefined,
  position: '2932',
  internalPosition: undefined,
  internalQuery: undefined,
  where: undefined,
  schema: undefined,
  table: undefined,
  column: undefined,
  dataType: undefined,
  constraint: undefined,
  file: 'scan.l',
  line: '1145',
  routine: 'scanner_yyerror'
}
[Nest] 7264   - 07/31/2020, 9:39:23 PM   [ExceptionsHandler] syntax error at or near "ORDER" +4042ms
QueryFailedError: syntax error at or near "ORDER"
    at new QueryFailedError (/home/albert/Documents/projects/rjx/backend/node_modules/typeorm/error/QueryFailedError.js:11:28)
    at Query.callback (/home/albert/Documents/projects/rjx/backend/node_modules/typeorm/driver/postgres/PostgresQueryRunner.js:176:38)
    at Query.handleError (/home/albert/Documents/projects/rjx/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/query.js:146:19)
    at Connection.connectedErrorMessageHandler (/home/albert/Documents/projects/rjx/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:236:17)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/albert/Documents/projects/rjx/backend/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:121:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:321:20)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:485:12)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:297:12)
```

When I remove the `.orderBy` line it's executed with no errors but what I want to achieve is to order entries by the position field's value present in the category table.

Comment: Help us help you - please share the error message

Comment: @Mureinik I've just posted the whole error traceback, would you please have a look?

Comment: It appears there is something wrong with whatever is in `whereClause`.

Comment: @MikeOrganek Aaaaah, spot on! it was because the `whereClause` contained `;` for some reason...very strange, I mean why would I put it in there...seems like a typo, yeah now it works as expected. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: I'm going to guess it was/is introduced by ```filters```.